# A Model of Dense Linear Orders without Endpoints

Tags: logic, model-theory

Hopefully this question is well defined. Consider the following linear order in the language $\{<\}$:

Step 0: Begin with $\mathbb{Q}$.

Step 1: Create a new model $Q_1$ by realizing all the types (cuts) in $S_1^\mathbb{Q}([-1,1])$.

Step 2: Create a new model $Q_2$ by realizing all the types (cuts) in $S^{Q_1}_1([-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}])$.

Step $n$: Create a new model $Q_{n}$ by realizing all the types (cuts) in $S^{Q_{n-1}}_1([-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}])$.

Now let $Q_\omega =\bigcup_{n<\omega}Q_n$.

Questions: Does $|S^{Q_\omega}_1(Q_\omega)|= \beth_\omega$? If **GCH** holds, then does $|S^{Q_\omega}_1(Q_\omega)|=|Q_\omega|$ and $Q_\omega$ is a stable dense linear order without endpoints? Is the stability of this model independent of **ZFC**?

Thanks.

Comment: $S_1^Q([-1,1])$ is the stone space with parameters from the interval $[-1,1]$. Every element of $S^Q_1([-1,1])$ is a type with parameters in $[-1,1]\cap Q$. We then "realize the types" of the non-standard elements in this space by adding elements to realize these types (namely, in the way one realizes a cut).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: No, a model, M, is stable (in this case) if for all $A \subseteq M$, $|S^M_1(A)|\leq|A|$.

Comment: So, for example in Step 1, we need to add an infinitesimal $\varepsilon$ with the property that it is larger than $0$ and smaller than every rational in $(0,1]$ -- and then in the same step we also need to add a fresh copy of $\mathbb Q$ between $0$ and $\varepsilon$ to make sure the order is still dense?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Exactly. Along with all the reals in the interval (since they also correspond to a cut).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your construction correctly, I don't see that $Q_\omega$ can have a cardinality higher than $\mathfrak c$. More precisely, each $x\in Q_\omega$ can be described by a finite sequence of reals as follows:

- If $x$ was added in step $n$ as the "principal" infintesimal right above or below an element of $y$ that already existed, describe it as $\langle n,\pm 1\rangle$ followed by the description of $y$.
- If $x$ was added in step $n$ as part of the "buffer copy" of $\mathbb Q$ betewen an already existing element $y$ and the infinitesimal above or below it, describe it as $\langle n,\pm2,q\rangle $ followed by the description of $y$, where $q$ is the location *within* the buffer copy.
- Otherwise, $x$ was added in step $n$ corresponding to an irrational cut in one of the "buffer copies" of $\mathbb Q$ from step $n-1$. Represent that as $\langle n-1,\pm2,\alpha\rangle$ where $\alpha$ is the irrational cut, and followed by the description of of the same $y$ that was used to describe the insertion of the buffer copy itself.

  (Once each of the cuts in each copy of $\mathbb Q$ has been filled in the next step, the subsequent steps *already* has that cut filled; it doesn't need to be replicated in subsequent steps. And every "cut of cuts" determines a cut we already know, either from above or below; that's the point of the reals being a *complete* order).

Thus $|Q_\omega|=\beth_1$, and $S_1^{Q_\omega}(Q_\omega)$ can't, as a matter of syntax, be larger than $\beth_3$ or thereabouts -- actually, with coding similar to those above, I think $S_1^{Q_\omega}(Q_\omega)$ ifself has cardinality $\mathfrak c$. In any case it's a far cry from $\beth_\omega$.

Comment: sorry for the delay. I'm not sure if I fully understand your argument. Furthermore, it doesn't feel right that $|S^{Q_1}_1([-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}])| = \mathfrak{c}$ (but again, you might be 100% correct). We have to consider more than the countable cuts, but also the cuts of size $\kappa$ for $\kappa \leq \beth_1$. Give me some time to think about your argument. Again, my apologies in the delayed response.

Comment: @Kyle: Perhaps it would be more manageable to start by agreeing whether $|S_1^{\mathbb R}(\mathbb R)|=\mathfrak c$? I hold that it is (assuming that $S_1(...)$ is the set of _complete_ 1-types) -- the important fact is that the only possible nontrivial cuts in $\mathbb R$ are $(-\infty,x]<(x,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,x)<[x,\infty)$ for some $x$ that already exists. There are no gaps in the reals that different cuts can be made with.

Comment: I think I understand where I got confused now! The problem is that I'm only adding a copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ to satisfy the new types. Otherwise, you are correct, you can find where everything is with "small" amounts of information. I need to rethink my construction. Thanks so much!